# Visual Studio 2010 suffers from Schizophrenia

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

at some point after installing VS2010, i performed a global search (ctrl + shift + F) adding *.xaml for file types.

well now that *.xaml is ALWAYS there the first time i search after opening solution.

i tried clearing that box and shutting down all instances of VS. but now, it ALWAYS insists on *.xaml so i have to clear this every time i open the solution.

also,

i always get that "you have mixed tabs and spaces" message up top, and i always select "Don't show again".

from what i can gather this a bug in vs2010?

Comment: yay! SO Police is here. i feel much safer now!

Answer (score 3):

Do you use some extenstions ? If you use Power tools try yo turn off option for mixed tabs. In tools options choose Productivity Power Tools and turn off fix mixed tabs.

Comment: you're right. that was part of power tools, disabled, thanks. still wondering about where vs keeps that *.xaml in file types though!